# Unit testing SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm trying to set up a unit test of a method that takes a SocketAsyncEventArgs, ie one of the IOCP functions from the Sockets class.

In order to shove one of these classes into my function, I need to change the .BytesTransferred property of the SAEA. How does one do this? I tried to use a PrivateObject.SetFieldOrProperty, but it tell me it's unable to find the property:

```
pargs.SetFieldOrProperty("BytesTransferred", expected);
```

I get the following exception:
"Method 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred' not found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property does not have a setter. Two solutions:

1. Don't use SocketAsyncEventArgs for testing. Instead, test on some kind of mock object.
2. Set the private field m_BytesTransferred. Use reflector to look at implementation details.

Solution #2 would make me nervous. I'd go with #1.

Comment: Is there an uncomplicated way to create a mock object?

Comment: You can find *tons* of information about isolated unit testing on the web.

Comment: Well, setting the m_name seems to have worked for me. I'll look at the mocks later.